# Angular2 ng build issue: Loading chunk x failed

Tags: angularjs, angular2-aot

I am building my angular application with following params
ng build --prod --env=production --aot

Above command always generate all new chunks, vendor and bundled files with a new hash file name. I am serving dist folder through Apache2 on Ubuntu server.

My problem is when I make a new build and serve new files from my server, all my users starts to get following errors

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Loading chunk 2 failed. ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Loading chunk 2 failed

Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

After I refresh the page everything works fine, but untill then all the user see white screen. Is there any way I can handle this error and reload the page with the code automatically?

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.24
node: 6.2.2
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.3
@angular/compiler: 2.4.3
@angular/core: 2.4.3
@angular/forms: 2.4.3
@angular/http: 2.4.3
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.3
@angular/router: 3.4.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.3
```

Answer (score -2):

I resolved this as follows: You can provide a custom implementation of `ExtraOptions` where you can perform any error handling as you like:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ExtraOptions} from "@angular/router";
import {ErrorHandler} from "@angular/router/src/router";

@Injectable()
export class CustomRoutingExtraOptions implements ExtraOptions {

    public errorHandler: ErrorHandler; // Overwrites attribute in ExtraOptions!

    constructor(/* inject any services you need here.. */) {
        this.errorHandler = error => {
            console.error('routing error: ', error);
            // any other custom handling..
        }
    }
}
```

You need to register this service in your module as follows:

```
import {ROUTER_CONFIGURATION} from "@angular/router";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ..
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot({...})
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: ROUTER_CONFIGURATION, useClass: CustomRoutingExtraOptions},
        ...
    ],

})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Alternatively (if you only need simple error handling), you can directly provide the error handler in the second parameter of `RouterModule.forRoot(..)`.